# Why does my designer.cs database file keep getting copied?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

Every time I write a line of code for one of my buttons or really do anything, Visual Studio copies my designer.cs file, so I end up getting over 11,000 errors, why does it keep copying that file?

[Screenshot showing the error I end up with.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFfrE.png)

Comment: Are you editing anything by hand in the designer files?

Comment: I am not, I am using a tableadapter to communicate between c# and the database.